# how to chose defualt first post in Elementor loop carousel widget

Tags: css, wordpress, elementor

i have post types Query that i order by date on Elementor loop carousel widget, i did it Infinite scroll , For the example that i attached i want by default that test6 will by first like exclude offset but without excluding the Previous post , witch plugin i need to use to do that with costumed loop item template?
Thanks

i ask Elementor pro support and they say that there is no option to do that on the widget so i am looking for a plugin that work same as loop carousel that i can chose what shown first without removing the Previouses posts.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: thanks , i found a solution..  not a prefect one but it help me for what i need

Comment: @Yossi you missed the point - this isn't a good question. SO is a Question&Answer site, which means questions should be useful to others, not just the poster. The "answer" you got was randomly generated by ChatGPT, which means you could have found out yourself if you simply *googled* for plugins. Essentially, you just tried the first two Google results without knowing you did so.

Comment: sorry its my first question on stack :(

Answer (score 1):

i try the "AnWP Post Grid for Elementor" plugin - i didn't find over there an option so i found a way, not perfect one but it help me..
i install the plugin "Advanced Post Queries".
and i add an advanced field with a different numbering to the posts with ACF Plugin.
and then i sorted the post in loop carousel widget by advanced order by option -> Dynamic order by field -> my post field.
and now its work great.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: sorry its my first question on stack :(

Answer (score -1):

There are a few plugins that might help you achieve what you’re looking for:

[Unlimited Elements for Elementor](https://unlimited-elements.com/docs/post-carousel): This plugin requires the PRO version installed and activated on your WordPress website1. It has a “Post Carousel” widget that you can add to any Elementor Page.

[AnWP Post Grid for Elementor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/anwp-post-grid-for-elementor): This plugin allows you to create a post grid for Elementor.

Please note that while these plugins offer similar functionalities to the Elementor Loop Carousel widget, they may not provide the exact feature of choosing the first post without excluding previous posts. You might need to do some custom coding or hire a developer to achieve this specific functionality.

Remember to always backup your site before installing a new plugin or making significant changes. Good luck

Comment: Thank for your answer! i will check those plugins to see if there is an option to chose the first one. trying to figure it out before coding.. thanks again!